# A beginner way to understand how time complexity works

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, sorting, time-complexity

I've been researching a lot about time complexity for my Data Structures class. And I've been tasked to report about Shell sort algorithm and explain its time complexity (best/worst/average case). I found this site https://stackabuse.com/shell-sort-in-java/ that shows that the time complexity of this Shell sort algorithm:

```
void shellSort(int array[], int n){ 
    //n = array.length
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
      for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
        int temp = array[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap){
          array[j] = array[j - gap];
        }
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

is **O(n log n)**. But the problem is that I'm still confused about makes logn a **logn** or what does nlogn means.

I also tried step count method but again, I don't know where to start so I just copied from the site above and did this.

```
void shellSort(int array[], int n){
    //n = array.length
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){                       //step 1 = runs logn times
      for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {                          //step 2 = runs n-gap times
        int temp = array[i];                                      //step 3 = 1
        int j;                                                    //step 4 = 1
        for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap){ //step 5 = i/gap times
          array[j] = array[j - gap];                              //step 6 = 1
        }
        array[j] = temp;                                          //step 7 = 1
      }
    }
  }
```

But I don't know if this is correct, I just based it off on this site. https://stackabuse.com/shell-sort-in-java/.

I've also tried comparing the total number of moves between Insertion Sort and Shell Sort since Shell Sort is a generalization of Insertion and Bubble Sort. I'll attach the pics below. I also used an online number generator that will give me **100 random numbers**, copied it and applied it to both the Insertion Sort and Shell sort and assigned it as the array to sort.

And this was what came up,

**Total number of moves of Insertion Sort** = 4731

**Total number of moves of Shell Sort** = 1954

[Shell Sort implementation that tells me the total number of moves it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ei7.jpg)

[Insertion Sort implementation that tells me the total number of moves it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlbLp.jpg)

What I've understood from all of this is that despite Shell sort being a generalization of Insertion sort, when it comes to sorting large arrays such as 100 elements Shell Sort is 2x faster than Insertion Sort.

But the ultimate question is, is there a beginner way to calculate the time complexity like this Shell Sort algorithm?

Comment: The time complexity stated in the site you used is incorrect. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences) states that shell sort using the gap sequence shown in the code has a worst case complexity of O(n^2). The formula shown on the site correctly calculates the complexity to be O(n^2) but the text erroneously states it is O(n log n) for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look at the big O or big Theta analysis of your function. Your outer loop is being divided by half on every iteration so the overall time that it runs is log n. Now when you look at your inner loop it runs initially from n/2 to n all the way to 1 to n or 2 to n depending on the initial size of n so its execution time will be n/2 + n/4 + .... n /2^k which its a 'Harmonic series' (You can search geometric series as well, if you factor n -> n(1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2^k) which equals n*logn. Now the best case where every list may be sorted to some extent will be Ω(n*logn) as the in the middle of the outer loop we will find optimal solution so we can say that n*logn is its lower bound - Meaning it is definitely equal or bigger than that  - therefor we can say that the average case is Θ(nlog^2 n) meaning that it is in the tight bound of that - Please note for average case I use Big theta. Now if we assume that the list is completely reverse the outer loop will run all the way to the end meaning log n. The inter loop will run n*logn so the total time will be n*log^2(n) which we can say it will be O(n*log^2(n)) (we can also use Big O but theta is better you can search that up that how theta provides tight bound and big O only provides upper bound). Therefore, we can also say the worst case is O(n^2) which is relatively correct in some context.

I suggest you take a look at Big-O and Big-Theta as well as Big-Omega which can also be useful in this case.

However, the most precise mathematical representation for shell algorithm will be O(n^3/2). However, there are still arguments and analyzation taking place.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The worst case complexity of shell sort with the gap sequence shown is precisely O(n^2), not O(n^(3/2)), which is for some other gap sequences.

Comment: I forgot to ask this but why do u say the inner loop runs nlogn times? Still quite confused

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll show that the algorithm will never be slower than `O(n^2)`, and then I'll show that the worst-case run time is at least `O(n^2)`.

Assume `n` is a power of two. We know the worst case for insertion sort is `O(n^2)`. When `h`-sorting the array, we're performing `h` insertion sorts, each on an array of size `n / h`. So the complexity for a `h`-sort pass is `O(h * (n / h)^2) = O(n^2 / h)`. The complexity of the whole algorithm is now the sum of `n^2 / h` where `h` is each power of two up to `n / 2`. This is a geometric series with first term `n^2`, common ratio `1 / 2`, and `log2(n)` terms. Using the geometric series sum formula gives `n^2*((1 / 2)^log2(n) - 1) / (1 / 2 - 1) = n^2*(1 / n - 1) / (-1 / 2) = n^2*(-2 / n + 2) = 2n^2 - 2n = O(n^2)`.

Consider an array created by interweaving two increasing sequences, where all elements in one sequence is greater than all elements in the other sequence, such as `[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]`. Since this array is two-sorted, all passes except the last one does nothing. In the last pass, an element at index `i` where `i` is even has to be moved to index `i / 2`, which uses `O(i / 2)` operations. So we have `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n / 2 = (n / 2) * (n / 2 + 1) / 2 = O(n^2)`.